# JS error during creating quote product

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-365

I have a big problem when adding product to quote. I narrowed this bug(?) to this situation and I can repeat it every time:

1. Create new organization
2. Customize quote entity to show list of related product - we want to add product using its main form (not quick create and not inline grid)
3. On customized quote form click add new product to show form like below
   [image]
4. On this form fill `Quantity` field with any value
5. Final part - click **twice** on `Pricing` so you will get `Override price` and back to `Use default`.

In my case after I click second time on `Pricing` I get JavaScript error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'errorCode' of null
at Object.<anonymous> (http://crodevcrm2/newcro/_common/JsProvider.ashx?bundle=FormControlBundle&ids=1223231347-405283869:11181:26)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://crodevcrm2/newcro/_common/JsProvider.ashx?bundle=JqueryBaseBundle&ids=727017229-892652631-1552783829:1497:44)
at j (http://crodevcrm2/newcro/_common/JsProvider.ashx?bundle=JqueryBaseBundle&ids=727017229-892652631-1552783829:1418:29)
at Object.add [as fail] (http://crodevcrm2/newcro/_common/JsProvider.ashx?bundle=JqueryBaseBundle&ids=727017229-892652631-1552783829:1437:69)
at Array.<anonymous> (http://crodevcrm2/newcro/_common/JsProvider.ashx?bundle=JqueryBaseBundle&ids=727017229-892652631-1552783829:1495:32)
at Function.each (http://crodevcrm2/newcro/_common/JsProvider.ashx?bundle=JqueryBaseBundle&ids=727017229-892652631-1552783829:209:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://crodevcrm2/newcro/_common/JsProvider.ashx?bundle=JqueryBaseBundle&ids=727017229-892652631-1552783829:1492:23)
at Function.Deferred (http://crodevcrm2/newcro/_common/JsProvider.ashx?bundle=JqueryBaseBundle&ids=727017229-892652631-1552783829:1518:34)
at Object.then (http://crodevcrm2/newcro/_common/JsProvider.ashx?bundle=JqueryBaseBundle&ids=727017229-892652631-1552783829:1490:26)
at Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.FormData.refresh (http://crodevcrm2/newcro/_common/JsProvider.ashx?bundle=FormControlBundle&ids=1223231347-405283869:11178:26)
```

But there is more...when I first fill all required fields like `Existing product`, `Unit`, `Quantity` and `Price per unit` and then click on `Pricing` record saves itself. When I change `Use legacy form rendering` to true in settings the error dissapears but save is still fired. There is no custom javascript here so what is the cause of this problem and how to fix this? **If anyone could reproduce this on his environment I would be very gratfull.**

I checked this on CRM 2016 (Update 1) and CRM 365 - both on-permise, both Polish language.

Comment: Were you able to fix this, or figure out what was causing it?

Comment: I created a ticket in MS and they said that this is by design...